# What is excludeParams actually excluding in Struts2?

Tags: java, parameters, struts2

I am a newbie in this area. When I'm going through interceptor basics in S2, I came across `struts-default.xml` and was a little confused about the `excludeParams` list.  Can anyone explain to me the code below and little about each parameter?

```
<interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well that is one of a feature provide by the framework to let you decide if you want all parameters or some selected parameters.

you can use this feature to decide and it sometime really very helpful where you want some specific properties to be accepted in your action class.

By default `Param interceptor` sets all parameters on the value stack.

This interceptor gets all parameters from `ActionContext#getParameters()` and sets them on the value stack by calling `ValueStack#setValue(String, Object)`, typically resulting in the values submitted in a form request being applied to an action in the value stack.

Under the hood XWork provide `MethodFilterInterceptor`, therefore being able to deal with excludeMethods / includeMethods parameters.

this is one of the mechanism provides by Struts2 to handle Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF).

Have a look at

1. [parameters-interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/parameters-interceptor.html)
2. [MethodFilterInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/MethodFilterInterceptor.html)

Comment: thanx for the great explanation. could you also please let me know little about each parameter(their use).

Comment: @Rocky_Rony: which parameters you are asking about? can you be more specific.

Comment: am Lill confused about these three ^servlet(Request|Response), dojo\..*,^struts\..*

Comment: @Rocky_Rony well interceptor stack defined by the framework exclude them since they are being used internally by the framework and they need not to get set by your action or param.though dojo is not much relevant now as it has been deprecated, regarding struts, since that is the namespace being used by the framework so it does not make sense to  set those values.same is case with servlet and application context as they are application specific and being set the S2 and container. for complete list refer here http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/struts-defaultxml.html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/parameters-interceptor.html)- This interceptor can be forced to ignored parameters, by setting its excludeParams attribute. This attribute accepts a comma separated list of regular expressions. When any of these expressions match the name of a parameter, such parameter will be ignored by the interceptor. Interceptor stacks defined by Struts already exclude some parameters:

```
   dojo\..* (anything parameter whose name contains "dojo.")
   ^struts\..* (any parameter whose name starts with "struts.")
```

Comment: Thanx for the response,I know what and how it does it.I want to know more about the parameters and reason why they are being listed here(mean to say problems if we don't list them).

Comment: Struts2 comes with "dojo" plugin. By default, parameters with names like "dojo" or "struts", you would be referring the framework components itself and you wouldn't want them to be intercepted. Hence they are by default configured not to be intercepted. Still, they are made configurable so that if for some reason, you want to intercept them, you can very well change the config and do the same.